# apache_mod_proxy & tomcat7 socket timeout

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-proxy, timeout, tomcat7, mod-proxy-ajp

I've configured Apache tomcat7 as backend & apache2.2 as frontend both on same CentOS 6 server & here is part of my configurations:

In `Server.xml` I have:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3" redirectPort="8443" connectionTimeout="600000" maxKeepAliveRequests="100" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
```

& in `httpd.conf`:

```
ProxyRequests Off
Timeout 600
ProxyTimeout 600
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

The problem is that some servlets on my tomcat server takes about 3 minutes to complete, but after one minute the opened socket to server (no matter what client I use, whether browser or any other client application) is closed by server unexpectedly (anyway, servlet execution continues until the end, even after socket was closed).
In `sysctl.conf` I changed value for `net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout` to `600` and I'm sure that it's not an OS timeout problem, because when I access another time-consuming script without mod_proxy (e.g. a PHP script with 3 minutes execution time on same apache server), it works fine with all clients.

Any suggestion will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up connection timeout in Proxy directive like below

```
ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/ connectiontimeout=600 timeout=600
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
```

I used these settings for my App and it was working fine

Comment: I've already tried it with no difference in the result!